# SUMIFS to Sum all rows that have 2 columns whose values match

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use `SUMIFS` to sum values in column Z when 2 conditions are present.

1. Column S contains:
2. Column Z = Column AA

I can make this work if I know the value like hardcoding it to "1300", but I need to compare each row to itself and not to a constant value like "1300".

```
=SUMIFS(AA4:AA311,S4:S311,"**",Z4:Z311,"1300")
```

How can I make this compare column Z to column AA for every row in the formula above?  In the example below I would expect all rows to be summed except for the first row with the data 540/200.

So the Sum would be:  5,783.90

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SUM(FILTER(AA2:AA; AA2:AA=Z2:Z; REGEXMATCH(S2:S; "")))
```

[image]